# Why decorator throws error of invalid type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Minimal example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const decorator = context => WrappedComponent => <WrappedComponent context={context}/>;

@decorator(1)
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return 1;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app-root'));
```

Errors:

> react.development.js:225 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid
>   -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally
>   export a JSX literal instead of a component?
>
> react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: object.

When I remove the decorator from the top of my component, everything works great.

---

babel config:

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ]
  ]
```

What is the problem with my decorator?

Comment: Please show the import statement for your decorator.

Comment: I don't have one, the name of it is: `decorator` and I implemented it above the component.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `JSX` code is not a valid expression, you should try to wrap in a class like that.

```
const decorator = (providedContext) => (WrappedComponent) => {
   return class extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount() {

      }
      render() {
         return <WrappedComponent context={providedContext}/>
      }
   }
}
```